# Weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 javax.interceptors issue

Tags: weblogic, upgrade, interceptor

In weblogic 12.1.x usage of @Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class) worked fine since javax.interceptor.Interceptors was part of wlfullclient.jar.

But in weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 it is an issue as wlfullcient.jar is deprecated. I do not find javax.interceptor.Interceptors  in wlthint3client.jar. How to use interceptors at the EJB level in weblogic 12.2.1.2? Is there an alternative to @interceptors in weblogic 12.2.1.2.0?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

javax.interceptor.Interceptors is part of [JavaEE](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/interceptor/Interceptors.html) since JavaEE 5. Add the missing dependency to your project.

eg. with maven and JavaEE7

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```